# First rows for selected cid then show the others rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have orders table like this:

```
OID CID ODATE 
1    1  01/01/21
2    2  01/02/21 
3    2  20/01/21 
4.   3. 20/01/21 
5.   4. 20/01/21
```

I want to see all the orders of cid 2 first then all the others
thanks ...

Comment: What is the expected output here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may order using a `CASE` expression:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY CASE CID WHEN 2 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END;
```

You may also add more sorting levels after the above `CASE` expression.